# What's the simplest way to classify directed tree edges with the Cytoscape.js API?

Tags: javascript, graph-theory, cytoscape.js

Assuming a directed rooted tree with n levels, and objects/edges already added to cytoscape, what's the simplest way to classify tree, forward, back, and cross edges?  Looking over the [API](https://js.cytoscape.org/), the simplest strategy looks like manual bfs/dfs, then using nodes.commonAncestors to distinguish forward from cross edges.  However, this also seems like a common enough use case that there might be something simpler.

Comment: Hi @Adam, can you please provide us with your current approach and a cytoscape.js snippet ([Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)). Thanks :)